# Can we use a combination of get() and put() on Salesforce maps?

Tags: apex, map

Can we use something like this on Salesforce maps?

```
map.get(Account.Id).put(some value);
```

Please suggest the correct syntax if this is way wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at the map class' [`put`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) method? It takes an *id* (`account.id`) and puts the value `some value` to the location of the key,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Map [put method syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_put) it associates key with value. So what you have added in your question is an invalid signature of method.

correct syntax is

```
map.put(key, value);
```

in your question context it can be in following way only

```
map.put(someotherMap.get(Account.Id),some value);
```